# How to add another maven project in post build actions in Jenkins

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins

I'm building my maven project using Jenkins which is having configurations for DEV and unit testing environments (pom.xml file). My project is getting built successfully.

Now I have one more maven project having selenium code and I want to build this project once the Dev maven project is built.

I'm checking out the project through git. 
How do I add my maven selenium project in post build actions in Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is what you are looking for: **Add post-build action > Build other projects** in Configuration. Note there are two types - one is for manual builds. Also, the *other project* needs to be on Jenkins too.

Comment: You mean "Trigger/Call builds in other projects" option in post build actions? If that is the one, I dont see any option to enter the maven version and root path to pom.xml

Comment: Its either **Build other projects**, **Build other projects (manual step)** or **Trigger parameterized build on other projects** (options available with Jenkins version 1.638). You need to reference another Jenkins project (your post-build project) in either of these. Prior to that, you will need to configure the other project.